# Explore Google drive of Google Cloud service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create a service account in Google Cloud platform. This service account has an email.

Is there any way I can login in the web portal of drive.google.com as this service account and see the files it owns or created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portal uses OAuth to authenticate and stores the Access Token within a cookie which includes session information. The portal has no method to use a service account. You will need to use the REST API or one of the SDKs to use a service account.